# Multithreaded Python Socket Sender/Client

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, twisted

I have a Twisted application that's listening for Int32StringReceiver messages and then re-sending them to another app.  Basically, it's a router, but it has some intelligence, introspecting where the data is going.

My problem is with the outbound side, getting lot of error messages, etc.

Inbound is a class Receiver(Int32StringReceiver):

```
def doActualForwarding(self, data):         
    self.stats.recvBits  += 8 * (4 + len(data))
    self.stats.recvMsgs += 1
    dlen = len(data) 
    if dlen > 1024*256:
        self.logger.info("router.Receiver.doActualForwarding(): data len: %s" % (dlen))
    self.router.forward(data)

def stringReceived(self, data):
    d = threads.deferToThread(self.doActualForwarding, data)
    d.addCallback(self.forwardingDoneOkay)
    d.addErrback(self.forwardingDoneError)
```

The self.router is instantiated object that needs to send these messages out via socket comms in the same format.  So, it just turns around and does this in the Router class:

```
def connect(self):
    if self.sock:
        try:
            self.sock.close()
        except:
            pass
    try:
        self.stats.connectAttempts += 1
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.settimeout(self.CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
        self.sock.connect(self.destination)
        self.sock.settimeout(self.SEND_TIMEOUT)
        self.set_keepalive_linux(self.sock)
        self.connected = True
        self.log.info("connected to %s" % (self.destination,))
        self.stats.reconnects += 1
        self.stats.connectCompletes += 1
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        self.connected = False
        if not self.drop_ok:
            self.log.error("connect %s: %s" % (self.destination, e))
        return False

def send(self, msg):
    trynum = 0
    while trynum < self.MAX_SEND_ATTEMPTS:
        self.logSent()
        if not self.connected:
            if not self.connect():
                self.stats.badSends += 1
                time.sleep(self.DELAY_BEFORE_RECONNECT)
                continue
        try:
            if ((time.time() - self.lastReconnectTime) > self.RECONNECT_EVERY):
                self.lastReconnectTime = time.time()
                assert False, "Reconnecting with destination to redistribute load."
            self.sock.sendall(msg)
            #self.closeSocket()
            self.stats.events += 1
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            whichKind = None
            if 'Broken pipe' in str(e):
                self.stats.brokenPipe += 1
            elif 'Resource temporarily unavilable' in str(e):
                self.stats.resourceTempUnavail += 1
            elif 'Bad file descriptor' in str(e):
                self.stats.badFileDescriptor += 1
            self.log.error("send: %s %s" % (str(self.destination), str(e)))
            try:
                self.sock.close()
            except:
                pass
            self.connected = False
            self.stats.badSends += 1
        trynum += 1
        if trynum == 1:
            self.stats.eventsWithRetry += 1
    if trynum > 1:
        self.log.warning("recon_sender.send(): Trynum non-singular, was: %s" % (trynum))
    return False

def __del__(self):
    try:
        self.sock.close()
    except:
        pass
```

QUESTIONS:

1. Is Python's Socket library threadsafe?  That is, functionally, two or more threads have a pointer to the object Router.  Both threads are calling self.sock.sendall(msg) and I'm concerned they'll step on each other.
2. One symptom is that it might be that successive messages are appended to each other. I'm not sure about this, but it looks that way.
3. I'm seeing a lot of resource temp. unavail (meaning destination is busy), about the same number of broken pipes, and a small number of bad file descriptor.

   - [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
   - [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
   - [Errno 32] Broken pipe

These messages correspond to maybe 0.5% (.005) of the number of messages going through this thing.

4. I tried to have each send do a connect/sendall/shutdown/close, but that resulted in a ton of messages about 'connection reset by peer'.

Everyone seems to be intent on code that handles multi-threaded receiving on sockets, but not so many comment on multi-threaded SENDING on sockets.

5. I also tried to use (possibly incorrectly):

   import threading
       self.lock = threading.Lock()
       with self.lock:
           sock.sendall(msg)

but this resulted in error messages about timing out (yuck).

6. Can someone point me in the direction of some good examples (Or PROVIDE SOME?!?!?!?) that demonstrate multithreaded socket sendall()?

Comment: Python in itself is generally not thread safe, so you will have to use multiprocessing to go around gil.

Comment: Is there a cause why you are deferring to a thread? It is not usual way to handle connections in Twisted and might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Twisted is not threadsafe and there is generally no reason to use threads to send network traffic within Twisted.  Why are you doing threading and low-level socket IO?  It's really not clear why you're not just calling `transport.write`...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the processes do not have to communicate with eachother, your best solution will be to spawn a new process to handle each incoming connection. This way you don't have to worry about locking as each connection will be handled separately.

Simple implementation would be:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing
import pdb
import random
from pycurl import Curl
import os
import time
import re

class query(object):
    pid, addr, conn, url, ua, ref = [None for i in range(6)]
    compression = True

    def __init__(self, conn, addr):
        self.pid = addr[1]
        self.addr = addr
        self.conn = conn
        self.process()

    def process(self):
        #do your socket stuff here

class ProxyServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def start(self):
        logging.info("Server started on %s:%i" % (self.host, self.port))
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(0)

        while True:
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            logging.info('Connection made from %s' % conn)
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=query, args=(conn, addr))
            proc.daemon = True
            proc.start()
            logging.info('Started processing query %r for %s' % (proc, addr))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serv = ProxyServer(host, port)
    try:
        serv.start()
    except:
    finally:
        for proc in multiprocessing.active_children():
            proc.terminate()
            proc.join()
```

Keep in mind that this is an example that I cut from old proof-of-concept code, you will have to tweak it a bit before it's ready for production.